# Router issue Express js with global variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, async-await

I'm developing routes for shopping cart. I wrote the code below

When I run this code the **cart** variable output is **undefined**

```
// Receive a post request to add an item to a cart
router.post('/cart/products', async (req, res) => {
  // Figure out the cart!
  let cart;
  if (!req.session.cartId) {
    cart = await cartsRepo.create({ items: [] });
    req.session.cartId = cart.id;
  } else {

    cart = await cartsRepo.getOne(req.session.cartId);
  }

  console.log(cart);

  res.send('Product added to cart');
});
```

Comment: If that is your actual code and you don't see any other errors (like _"Cannot read property 'id'..."_), then `cartsRepo.getOne(req.session.cartId)` is returning a promise that resolves with `undefined`. What debugging have you done?

Comment: Why are you modifying `req.session.cartId` in the if block?

Comment: @SagarKulkarni I did this to update cart id so once the same user add/update the products. They have to be added to the same cart.